# waitForText is not working to locate text but waitUntil works

Tags: karate

I am getting ready to pull my hair out. Not sure what I am doing wrong but here is the issue:

I have a textbox for which I am verifying an error message for. The html looks something like this:

```
<span class="text-field-error" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span id="Name-error" class="">There are invalid characters being used.</span></span>
```

My xpath to locate the error message looks something like this:

```
//span[@id='Name-error']
```

I am using the following command to verify the error message:

```
driver.waitForText('//span[@id='Name-error']','There are invalid characters being used.')
```

This verification fails.

However, when I try the following command, it works fine.

```
driver.waitUntil('//span[@id='Name-error']',"_.innerText.includes('There are invalid characters being used.')")
```

I have verified there is no hidden whitespace in the first instance. I have to use waitForText vs waitUntil to keep up with coding standards within my project.

Please advise, Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea, maybe it is a bug. If you can provide a way to replicate, that will help the community: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test

Meanwhile see if this works:

```
waitForText('body', 'There are invalid characters being used')
```

I can't help noticing that you are not using double-quotes when needed.

```
waitForText("//span[@id='Name-error']", 'There are invalid characters being used')
```

Comment: I actually have the xpath wrapped in a variable, but yes, otherwise, I would've wrapped it in double quotes. I will try to reproduce with a sample form and report back. Thanks.

Comment: It was user error. My apologies. I used highlight() to make sure it was catching the xpath. Then I figured it was an issue with the text. Turns out, there was no hidden space on the text on the page, but there was hidden text in the actual html text. That is why waitUntil worked and waitUntilText didn't. Thank you @Peter Thomas.